# Developing Android App Installs fine after Uninstall will Not Reinstall

Tags: android

I have a small app that i have been working on. I wanted a fresh install to run from on my Galaxy Nexus rooted running 4.2.1. I uninstalled the app, then tried to reinstall it via eclipse. It installs fine, no errors in logcat, console ect... but when you click to run the app, it just closes right on opening. I have tried this on 2 different phones, same thing.

On the Galaxy Nexus, if I restore my ROM back before I uninstalled, I can run it from eclipse all I want. It's only after uninstall and reinstall that I get the force close. It is installed on the ROM backup.

Any ideas?! How can I find out what is going on here?

EDIT:::

Activity is only declared once in manifest...

Tried changing the version number... no effect

added some Log.e() to the MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e(TAG,"STARTING APP");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // show no back arrow
        Log.e(TAG,"AFTER ONCREATE");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstload);
        Log.e(TAG,"AFTER SETCONTENTVIEW");

        getPrefs();
        Log.e(TAG,"GET PREFS");
        finish();
        Log.e(TAG,"AFTER FINISH");
    }
```

The only tag that shows in the LogCat is "AFTER FINISH"

If I get rid of finish, the MainActivity stays open. All that main activity does is check for Preferences. Here is my GetPrefs()

```
private void getPrefs() {
        // Get the xml/preferences.xml preferences
        Log.e(TAG,"GET PREFS 1");
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        lp = prefs.getString("defaultreport", "");
        Log.v(TAG, lp);

        if (lp.equals("esac")) {
//          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ESAC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                  .show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ESACActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (lp.equals("sac")) {
//          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SAC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                  .show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SACActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (lp.equals("msar")) {
//          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MSAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                  .show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MSARActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
```

AH>>> May have found something. The preferences initially are set to "" (null) so what would it load?! So I need a screen asking which they'd like to set on FIRST RUN I guess...

EDIT EDIT::: Needed to check for first run in Prefs...

```
if (prefs.getString("defaultreport", null) == null)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Preferences.class));
            return;
        }
```

Comment: when you try to run it, are there any errors occuring?

Comment: Nothing I can see at all. That is the crazy part! I cleared LogCat... Nothing shows. I Cleared the Console and the normal stuff shows... No errors in the error log... nothing!

Comment: try to add logs in very beginning of onCreate of ur mainActivity

Comment: "Did you try turning it off and on?" lol. But seriously, try disconecting your phone, restarting it. Close eclipse, restart it. Uninstall the app before you do all that. Then try to connect it again and install. I have been having issues with eclipse lately and the device connections so it may be similiar.

Comment: @KalelWade yes, i just did that. That was my first thought... restart eclipse, then phone... nothing. Strange!

Comment: @AND_DEV Thanks for the reminder, I narrowed it down with many Log.e() :)

Comment: it may be error in another activity you are trying to open, add logs in onCreate there too. Dont add too much condition. comment out all the code and narrow it down. what making it to crash. dont call finish from onCreate, add it after startActivity method call in getpref it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string that decides what to run is set to nothing if there is no preference.

```
lp = prefs.getString("defaultreport", "");
```

And since you have no option for that case nothing will run and the initial activity will close without starting any other.

Comment: I got that after about an hour of wondering, but you are correct, so I am accepting your answer. Thanks!